# Is there a way to upgrade and maintain dependencies programmatically for all Spring boot projects in a microservice architecture?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, microservices, project-structure

In a Spring boot microservice architecture you have many project folders each representing each service. I'd assume you have mult-module maven project with all services each having their own subdirectory in a parent folder, each having their own maven dependencies.

For maintainability and to keep all services updated with the latest dependencies how would you for example upgrade to the latest Spring BOM or upgrade a third party library like Apache commons for all services?

Comment: using versions-maven-plugin to update in relationship with a script ?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to automatically updated dependencies, I'd recommend going latest-1 to avoid the risk of any undiscovered bugs. Unless you are 100% confident in your automated tests.

You can configure the maven versions plugin to do this, and could get it to re-commit back to your repo.

http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/advancing-dependency-versions.html

`versions:use-latest-releases`

You can configure it to ignore, major/minor/patch versions.

http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html

E.g. if you didn't want to automatically advance to Spring 5.0/Spring Boot 2.0 `versions:use-latest-releases -DallowMajorUpdates=false` and/or include/exclude depenedencies you want to handle manually.